# Leaflet.js choropleth example - updating color based on separate data file

Tags: javascript, leaflet

This [Leaflet.js choropleth example](http://leafletjs.com/examples/choropleth.html) assigns polygon color based on the geoJSON file density values.

```
function getColor(d) {
    return d > 1000 ? '#800026' :
           d > 500  ? '#BD0026' :
           d > 200  ? '#E31A1C' :
           d > 100  ? '#FC4E2A' :
           d > 50   ? '#FD8D3C' :
           d > 20   ? '#FEB24C' :
           d > 10   ? '#FED976' :
                      '#FFEDA0';
}
```

This updates each polygon's color in `function style(feature)`

```
function style(feature) {
    return {
        fillColor: getColor(feature.properties.density),
        weight: 2,
        opacity: 1,
        color: 'white',
        dashArray: '3',
        fillOpacity: 0.7
    };
}
```

and this new style is added to the map

```
L.geoJson(statesData, {style: style}).addTo(map);
```

However in my situation, my equivalent of the example's `statesData` geoJSON file doesn't have the density value in it.

Instead I have the density values in a separate data file that I used to create new array. This array has state `name` values and density values

```
var my_array = [
    ['name': 'alabama', 'density': 59], 
    ['name': 'alaska', 'density': 30], 
    etc 
]
```

The question is how to relate the `name` string values in both the geoJSON file and the separate data file so that I can get the associated density values  into `function style(feature)` to change polygon colors?

This is likely not necessarily a Leaflet.js question but could a general Javascript 'how to' question.

So far I can loop through `my_array` and create a new array with `name` and color values.

```
color_array = []
for(var i=0; i < my_array.length; i++) {
   color_array.push([my_array[i][0] + ', ' +  getColor(my_array[i][1])]);
}
```

To get new `color_array`

```
color_array = [ 
['alabama', '#FFEDA0'],
['alaska', '#FEB24C'],
etc
]
```

Now how can I use this new `color_array` with the `function style(feature)` so that the color is set correctly for each `name` ?

In SQL I would do a join on `name` and feed the `name` and related density value to the `getColor` function with output being the `name`, density and color.

How can that be done in javascript?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can probably skip step of creating the color array up front unless you need to cache it for performance reasons.

Just do this:

```js
var my_array = [{
  'name': 'alabama',
  'density': 59
}, {
  'name': 'alaska',
  'density': 30
}];

function getColor(density) {
  if (density > 30) return 'blue';
  return 'red';
}

function getStateColor(stateName) {
  var color;
  for (var i = 0; i < my_array.length; i++) {
    if (my_array[i].name === stateName) {
      color = getColor(my_array[i].density);
      break;
    }
  }
  return color;
}

alert("alabama = " + getStateColor('alabama'));
```

Then you can do this

```
function style(feature) {
    return {
        fillColor: getStateColor(feature.properties.stateName),
        weight: 2,
        opacity: 1,
        color: 'white',
        dashArray: '3',
        fillOpacity: 0.7
    };
}
```

Comment: You could even convert `my_array` first to a hash / dictionary, so you get a direct translation from State name to density or color. Instead of having to loop through it for each State.

Comment: yeah, there is a lot we can do to simplify and optimize this code. hard to know where to draw the line sometimes so usually try to focus on the core issue which in this case is demonstrating that the data used to determine `fillColor` doesn't need to solely come from the features' properties

Comment: Indeed the pedagogical approach is very important :-)

Comment: Yes pedagogical approach suitable here : ) Ok I see, `getStateColor` function is the join query and `my_array[i].name === stateName` is the where clause. I do lots of SQL and some VBA, PHP & Python but javascript always seems a bit squirrelly to me. This helps thanks.

Comment: Glad to help, but uhhhh.. if you really want to make a SQL analogy `getStateColor` is more like a subquery than a join (it queries the state attributes table to get the density), but really is more like a `PL/SQL` function :P

Comment: OK, you asked for it: `select state_name, (select max(color) from density_color where density >= (select density from state_attributes where state_name=state.state_name) and density < (select density from state_attributes where state_name=state.state_name)) as color from state`

Comment: Excellent : ) I was thinking bit more simple: `select s.state_name, case when d.density > 30 then 'blue' else 'red' end as color
from state s join density_color d on s.state_name = d.state_name`

Comment: Yep, you got it. `case` works for sure. most of the stuff I build ends up with user-defined classes/colors and so I just tend to think of it that way, but it also seemed like a good analogy because of the way the the code was designed